# How to create firewall isolated pages using Simile's timeline and map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, simile

I have experimented with Simile's [exhibit](http://www.simile-widgets.org/exhibit/) and have saw the usefulness of the graphical display via a prototype implementation on machines which have access to the internet.  We have to migrate the prototype from the open internet to a closed intranet, where only internal servers are available.

The timeline seems feasible, but maps dependency on Google seems a deal breaker.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Maps API [Terms](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html#section_9_1) require that your map is free and available to the public.  If you want to put it on a private intranet, you'll have to purchase the [Premier](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/premier/) version

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use OpenLayers maps in a simile exhibit project. See the docs at:

http://www.simile-widgets.org/wiki/Exhibit/OpenLayers_Map_View

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in the [Timemap.js library](http://code.google.com/p/timemap/) (disclaimer: this is my project), which offers utilities for using a SIMILE Timeline widget with maps from a variety of providers, including OpenLayers. Example here: http://timemap.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.0/examples/basic_openlayers.html

OpenLayers can be used on a closed network, as long as you can provide map tiles locally.